# Version number in .ipa file behind auto-incremented version in info.plist file

Tags: xcode, bash

I have a run script in my build phases to autoincrement my build version every time I run a release build.  It increments my info.plist file and root.plist file as expected.  However, in Organizer, the version listed for the archive is always the number from the version prior to running the script (one less than I would expect).  I have my run script ordered to runafter Target Dependencies and before Compile Sources.

Here is my build script.

```
if [ $CONFIGURATION == Release ]; then
echo "Bumping build number..."
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"

productVersion=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")

IFS='.'
set $productVersion
MAJOR_VERSION="${1}.${2}"
buildNewVersion="${MAJOR_VERSION}.${buildNumber}"

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $buildNewVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set PreferenceSpecifiers:9:DefaultValue $buildNewVersion" SmartView/Resources/Settings.bundle/Root.plist
fib
```

Comment: Someone edited my request.  The question is how do I get the version number in my ipa file to increment.

Answer (score 0):

If this script is running after Target Dependencies, then I bet there is a dependency that's including the version somewhere. Have you tried running this before dependencies?